# Error with observer in web service API in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, invoke

I have created an API Web Server using kotlin using the *Ktor* framework.

This service has only 1 method: `get`; in this method I have an oberserver to observe some LiveData, but I am getting the following error:

```
"Cannot invoke observe on a background thread"
```

Here is the code:

```kotlin
private lateinit var verViewModel: VerificationViewModel
    private  lateinit var qrCodeText: String
    var certStatus: String = "vuoto"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        verViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[VerificationViewModel::class.java]
        embeddedServer(Netty, 8080)
        {
            install(StatusPages) {
                exception<Throwable> { e ->
                    call.respondText(e.localizedMessage, ContentType.Text.Plain, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                }
            }
            install(ContentNegotiation)
            {
                gson {}
            }
            routing{
                route("/getStatus") {
                    get("{qrText}") {
                        certStatus ="vuoto"
                        qrCodeText = CastNullableString(call.parameters["qrText"])
                        validateGreenPass(qrCodeText)
                        call.respond(Response(status = certStatus))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start(wait=true)
    }
    data class Response (val status: String)
    fun CastNullableString(str:String?):String
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            return ""
        }
        else
        {
            return str
        }
    }
    private fun validateGreenPass(qrCodeText: String)
    {
        try
        {
            val certObserver = Observer<CertificateSimple?> { (_, _, certificateStatus) ->  certStatus=certificateStatus.toString()}
            verViewModel.certificate.observe(this,certObserver)
            verViewModel.decode(qrCodeText, false);
        }
        catch (e: Exception)
        {
           certStatus = "ERROR: " + CastNullableString(e.message)
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how to help me?